# Error when trying to activate a user [Permission Set License limit]

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, licenses

I'm trying to activate a User and I'm getting this error:

***All Field Service Dispatcher permission set licenses are in use. For more licenses, contact your salesforce.com representative.***

I tried:

-Go to Setup > Permission Sets > Field Service Dispatcher permission > Removing the assignment to several users (active users).

-Go to Setup > Users > Select User with this permission license > Permission Set License Assignments Related List > Delete the Field Service Dispatcher License

After that, I tried to activate the user and the error still happening. What is the problem?

Comment: Before you can create the permission set for your Field Service users, verify that your org has Field Service enabled. From Setup, go to Customize | Field Service | Field Service Settings and verify that Field Service is enabled.